# How we can use on mouse hover action in sub menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

1. I've one link, link name is 'Orders'
2. On mouse over it shows a drop down and drop down has some values like accessioning, dos management, lab management etc. It shows values only after hovering the mouse.
3. Now I've to select 'Accessioning' value from this drop down.

[image]
Please help for clicking the submenu

Comment: Please update with HTML or at least a screenshot of the page.

Comment: @bad_deadpool Please have a look at my code and let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Code should be in the question itself, formatted as code. Do not post or link to screenshots of text. (Note that no one can even see the link without editing your question.)

Answer (score 0):

this is handled using `Actions` class' `moveToElement()` method in selenium;

```
WebElement orders=driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\xpath\to\your\orders\element"));
WebElement Accessioning=driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\xpath\to\your\orders\element"));

action.moveToElement(orders).moveToElement(Accessioning).build().perform();
```

**UPDATED:**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://biotdev.technossustest.com/Workflow/Worklist2.aspx");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_LoginContent_MainLogin_UserName")).sendKeys("hmeyer");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_LoginContent_MainLogin_Password")).sendKeys("spivulet");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_LoginContent_MainLogin_LoginImageButton")).click();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_PassowrdChangeNotification_OkPushButton")).click();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement menuItem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_MainMenun5 > table"));
        WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_MainMenun23 > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a"));


        action.moveToElement(menuItem).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        action.moveToElement(subMenu).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with this and it's resolved, thankiew Kushal for your help.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("ctl00_DefaultContent_WorklistCtrl_WorklistTable")));

WebElement menu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainMenun5']//td[2]"))));     
Actions action = new Actions(driver);


action.clickAndHold(menu).build().perform();
WebElement item = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainMenun23']//a[text()='Accessioning']"));
item.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the Robot class...

```
Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath/id(xpathString/id)).getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY());
```

Above code wont work with headless environment.